# Apply Custom attributes to Code First Entity framework Objects

Tags: c#, attributes, entity-framework-6, custom-attributes

Is it possible to apply custom attributes to code first entity framework objects without entity framework discarding them at runtime?

I want to decorate my class objects with not only data annotations relating to Entity Framework specific conditions, but to also include custom attributes to the classes that refer to other areas of my project, for e.g, Lucene.Net, where i may wish to declare Field specific attributes regarding a Lucene field or index.

If anyone has had experience of doing something similar to this I'd appreciate some advice or useful links.

Comment: Maybe they're ignored at runtime due to EF Proxying the real classes? What indications are there that the attributes are being ignored?

Comment: I think its the EF Conventions that ignores them, but i cant be sure.

Comment: My problem is similar, I need to bind a subset of Entity properties to a (Telerik) Kendo grid

My first thought is to create an factory for anonymous types.  Basically feed Entity in, out pops an anonymous type with only the properties i need to populate the grid. Nice solution because

a) no duplication

b) less places to maintain data layer changes

What did you end up doing for your solution

Possibly there is another better option I haven't thought of. Or i'd be very interested to know how this worked out for you if this is the route you went down.

Appreciate any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing code first you should be able to add whatever attributes you want. Since you're not generating the entities through a designer they won't be deleted.

Comment: there not deleted, but ignored at runtime.

Comment: Can you post some sample code? I might be misunderstanding you, but in what way are they being ignored? It makes sense that they are ignored by EF, but your own custom code targeting them should still discover them on the properties...

Comment: I'll post my code tomorrow, from work. I think it EF conventions that's doing it.